# Apache JMeter accepting expired SSL certificate

Tags: jmeter, soapui

I observed while testing an external web service from my java program is returning:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed

But the same URL is accessible via Jmeter and SOAP UI. Based on some googling seems SOAP UI ignores hostname verification and expired certs checks but not getting enough information on Jmeter.

Does Jmeter ignores SSL handshakes error when certs are expired? Appreciate any help to enforce such validation.

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter doesn't do any check on certificate :

- It accepts certificates invalid for current hosts
- It accepts expired certificates

This is to allow using it in QA Environment where both conditions are very frequent

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a option to force these checks.